# Pixelated brush Strokes

Tags: modeling, texturing, texture-painting

[image]

It is a low poly model, when I am using brush in small size it is making these dotted lines instead to solid stroke. The UV image is 2k*2k, still I am getting these pixelated result. I am only paining colors in the model.
How can I solve this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you checked the Stroke panel > Spacing value? Bring it back to 10% if it was not already.

Comment: Spacing value is already in 10%, I even tried turning it to 1%.

Comment: maybe share your file (just this part)? upload and copy paste the URL: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/87ecc9fd7c5a4cd39698d7f8d6694ccf
this is the blend file..
https://pasteall.org/pic/7df5eece93ec49679e185f0b4e60df0e
and this is the texture png

Comment: it works fine for me, maybe your image (or the UV island) is too small?

Comment: I just uploaded the UV image..

Comment: weird because it works fine for me: https://zupimages.net/up/22/15/pnwb.gif

Comment: try using a smaller brush size (like 1-2 px) while zoomed in.

Comment: it looks like a radius of 1 or 2 are below the size of your image pixel, so I guess it decides to draw a pixel every *n* pixels. For example if you scale up the size of your original image (like 4000 x 4000) it will works twice better

Comment: Thanks You so much, for your help...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if you zoom too much, a brush radius of 1 or 2 is below the size of your image pixel, so I guess it draws a pixel every *n* pixels, therefore these dots. But if you scale up the size of your original image (like 4000 x 4000) it will works twice better, or just increase the brush size up to 10, you'll have the same thickness and less dots.

You'll see more clearly what's happening if you switch your *Image Texture* from *Linear* (which blurs the pixels) to *Closest* . With this option you'll see the real image and the real pixel size, and the difference between the pixel size and the brush size. 1 or 2 is much too small compared to the pixel size of your image. Here the brush size is 15:

[image]

Comment: moonboots is *the* best

Comment: @BlenderMaster far from it but i try, i try  ;)